# Keeping the absolute position of an equation

Tags: beamer, equations, positioning

I have a slide with a single lemma (block) in which there is an equation. I wish that the next slide will contain that equation, but in the same absolute position. Currently, if I just centre the equation in the next slide, it "moves" when I pass slide.

Is there a way to somehow record/save the position of the equation in the lemma and then apply it absolutely to the (same) equation on the next slide?

One other option is to stay in the same slide, leave the equation somehow untouched but remove the lemma block environment and the rest of the text in it.

I hope this all makes sense. It would simply look much better that way.

## Update - MWE

```
\documentclass[utf8]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Key lemma}
  \begin{lemma}
    Let $x,y,z$ be variables.  Then, almost surely,
    \begin{equation*}
      x = y = z.
    \end{equation*}
  \end{lemma}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Key lemma}
  \begin{equation*}
    x = y = z.
  \end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You can see that the equation "moves".

Comment: I guess `\visible` could help - but without a MWE that's just a guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\visible` is your friend:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<1-2>{Key lemma}
    \visible<1>{
  \begin{lemma}
    Let $x,y,z$ be variables.  Then, almost surely,
   }
    \begin{equation*}
      x = y = z.
    \end{equation*}
  \visible<1>{
  \end{lemma}
  }
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No, you are my friend! :)